not-null property references a null or transient value when using Postman
I am trying to create a simple parts management app using java and spring framework.
I have a Parts entity and a MaterialLists entity. I am using Postman.co to POST my sample data. I can successfully POST to my Parts entity but am getting an error when trying to POST to the MaterialLists entity.
The error:
app-1  | 2024-07-15T17:18:03.404Z DEBUG 1 --- [io-8081-exec-10] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.lbx.parts.entity.MaterialList.materialList]
How can I solve this error?
Below are my entities and my JSON POST:
package com.lbx.parts.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.Date;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "Parts")
@Table
public class Parts {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String partNumber;
    private String description;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String supplier;
    private String serialNumber;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PartStatus status;

    private String category;
    private int quantityOnHand;
    private String storageLocation;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date expirationDate;

    private int minQuantity;
    private int maxQuantity;
    private double cost;
    private int leadTime;
    private String processCriticality;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "material_list_id", nullable = false)
    private MaterialLists materialList;

    public enum PartStatus {
        ACTIVE,
        INACTIVE
    }
}

package com.lbx.parts.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.List;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class MaterialLists {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long materialListID;

    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "materialList", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Parts> parts;

    public void addPart(Parts part) {
        parts.add(part);
        part.setMaterialList(this);
    }
}

package com.lbx.parts.service.impl;

import com.lbx.parts.dto.MaterialListsDto;
import com.lbx.parts.entity.MaterialLists;
import com.lbx.parts.entity.Parts;
import com.lbx.parts.mapper.MaterialListsMapper;
import com.lbx.parts.mapper.PartsMapper;
import com.lbx.parts.repository.MaterialListsRepository;
import com.lbx.parts.service.MaterialListsService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MaterialListsServiceImpl implements MaterialListsService {

    private final MaterialListsRepository materialListRepository;

    @Override
    public MaterialListsDto createMaterialList(MaterialListsDto materialListsDto) {
        MaterialLists materialLists = MaterialListsMapper.mapToMaterialLists(materialListsDto);

        // Set the material list reference in each part
        if (materialLists.getParts() != null) {
            for (Parts part : materialLists.getParts()) {
                part.setMaterialList(materialLists);
            }
        }

        MaterialLists savedMaterialLists = materialListRepository.save(materialLists);
        return MaterialListsMapper.mapToMaterialListsDto(savedMaterialLists);
    }

    @Override
    public MaterialListsDto getMaterialListById(Long materialListId) {
        MaterialLists materialLists = materialListRepository.findById(materialListId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid material list Id:" + materialListId));
        return MaterialListsMapper.mapToMaterialListsDto(materialLists);
    }

    @Override
    public List<MaterialListsDto> getAllMaterialLists() {
        List<MaterialLists> materialLists = materialListRepository.findAll();
        return materialLists.stream()
                .map(MaterialListsMapper::mapToMaterialListsDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public MaterialListsDto updateMaterialList(Long materialListId, MaterialListsDto updatedMaterialListDto) {
        MaterialLists materialLists = materialListRepository.findById(materialListId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid material list Id:" + materialListId));

        materialLists.setDescription(updatedMaterialListDto.getDescription());
        materialLists.setParts(updatedMaterialListDto.getParts().stream()
                .map(PartsMapper::mapToParts)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        // Set the material list reference in each part
        if (materialLists.getParts() != null) {
            for (Parts part : materialLists.getParts()) {
                part.setMaterialList(materialLists);
            }
        }

        MaterialLists updatedMaterialLists = materialListRepository.save(materialLists);
        return MaterialListsMapper.mapToMaterialListsDto(updatedMaterialLists);
    }

    @Override
    public MaterialListsDto deleteMaterialList(Long materialListId) {
        MaterialLists materialLists = materialListRepository.findById(materialListId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid material list Id:" + materialListId));
        materialListRepository.delete(materialLists);
        return MaterialListsMapper.mapToMaterialListsDto(materialLists);
    }
}

my GET for Parts:
[
    {
        "id": 10002,
        "partNumber": "PN-001",
        "description": "Part Number 001",
        "manufacturer": "Manufacturer A",
        "supplier": "Supplier A",
        "serialNumber": "SN-001",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "category": "Category A",
        "quantityOnHand": 100,
        "storageLocation": "Location A",
        "expirationDate": "2025-12-31",
        "minQuantity": 10,
        "maxQuantity": 200,
        "cost": 10.5,
        "leadTime": 5,
        "processCriticality": "High"
    },
    {
        "id": 20004,
        "partNumber": "PN-00123",
        "description": "Description of the part",
        "manufacturer": "Manufacturer Name",
        "supplier": "Supplier Name",
        "serialNumber": "SN-00123",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "category": "Category Name",
        "quantityOnHand": 50,
        "storageLocation": "Location A",
        "expirationDate": "2024-12-31",
        "minQuantity": 10,
        "maxQuantity": 100,
        "cost": 25.75,
        "leadTime": 14,
        "processCriticality": "High"
    },
    {
        "id": 30002,
        "partNumber": "PN-12345",
        "description": "Sample Part 1",
        "manufacturer": "Manufacturer A",
        "supplier": "Supplier A",
        "serialNumber": "SN-12345",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "category": "Category A",
        "quantityOnHand": 10,
        "storageLocation": "Location A",
        "expirationDate": "2024-12-31",
        "minQuantity": 5,
        "maxQuantity": 50,
        "cost": 100.0,
        "leadTime": 7,
        "processCriticality": "High"
    }
]

my attempt to POST MaterialLists
{
    "description": "Sample Material List",
    "parts": [
        {
            "partNumber": "PN-12345",
            "description": "Sample Part 1",
            "manufacturer": "Manufacturer A",
            "supplier": "Supplier A",
            "serialNumber": "SN-12345",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "category": "Category A",
            "quantityOnHand": 10,
            "storageLocation": "Location A",
            "expirationDate": "2024-12-31",
            "minQuantity": 5,
            "maxQuantity": 50,
            "cost": 100.0,
            "leadTime": 7,
            "processCriticality": "High"
        }
    ]
}



The code you've listed doesn't match up with the exception; what is MaterialListPart?  On a side note, you should never use @Data on your entities.  If you want to use Lombok on them, use only @Getter and @Setter.  You do not need an all args constructor and a no arg constructor is implied so you can drop both of those.

A PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value occurs when attempting to save a null value into a field marked with nullable = false.
In this case, it seems that 'materialList' is null.
